# code using heappop() is working but when using array representation its not working

Tags: python, syntax, heap, heapsort

Its a leetcode question I have been working on https://leetcode.com/problems/last-stone-weight/ , the code seems to accepting using the following snippet of code

```
   a= heapq.heappop(stones1);
   b= heapq.heappop(stones1);
   heapq.heappush(stones1,a-b);
```

but when this is used it doesn't seem to be working ,

```
   a=stones1[0];
   b=stones1[1];
   heapq.heappop(stones1);
   heapq.heappop(stones1);
   heapq.heappush(stones1,a-b);
```

don't both the codes represent the same thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the working code...

```
a= heapq.heappop(stones1);
b= heapq.heappop(stones1);
```

...`a` and `b` represent the least and one-but-least values in the heap (as it was before the extracting was initiated).

True, the least value always sits at index 0 in the heap, so this is correct:

```
a=stones1[0];
heapq.heappop(stones1);
```

However, it is *not* always true that the one-but-least value is sitting at index 1 in the heap. It might be sitting at index 2. So this is not always correct:

```
a=stones1[0];
b=stones1[1];
heapq.heappop(stones1);
heapq.heappop(stones1);
```

Here is an example with a visualisation of a heap:

```
              1
             / \
            3   2
```

In list representation, this is [1, 3, 2]

After executing `heapq.heappop(stones1)`, this list becomes [2, 3]. So now the value you'd want in `b` has moved from index 2 to index 0. It will get popped when executing `heapq.heappop(stones1)` again.